# Unbale to create table using SQLite in Ionic 4

Tags: sqlite, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic4

The following is my component code

```
import { SQLite, SQLiteObject } from '@ionic-native/sqlite'; 

constructor(private sqlite: SQLite){
    this.createTransactions();
}

createTransactions(){
   this.sqlite.create({
     name: 'sample.db',
     location: 'default'
   }).then((db: SQLiteObject) => {
         db.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions(transaction_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, user_id TEXT, order_date DATE, order_number INTEGER, invoice_date DATE, processed_date DATE, transaction_amount FLOAT)')
         .then(res => alert('Executed SQL'))
         .catch(e => alert('cannot create table'+JSON.stringify(e))); //alerting this
   }).catch(e => alert('lite'+JSON.stringify(e)));
}
```

can somebody tell me where am doing wrong?

Comment: What feedback from any of the `alerts` are you getting?

Comment: Thanks for replying. It has been resolved after checking the documents thoroughly